# boost c++ serialize/deserialize

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

Can someone give me an example of serialization/deseralization using the Boost library? I am working in c++/ubuntu 9.1

I have the class

```
class x
{
public:
    x();

    std::string name;
    std::string surname;
};
```

How can I create XML `<1.0...> id: <name>..<surname>` using boost serialization? Or is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

boost serialization will build its own XML schema which is not modifiable.
Serialization is for serialization not reading/writing random XML.

Answer (score 0):

boost is overkill for such a trivial example... I mean, all you need is

```
friend std::ostream& (std::ostream& str, x const & cData)
{
  return str << "<...><name>" << cData.name << "</name><surname>" << cData.surname << "</surname></...>";
}
```

Comment: This looks like a direct route to producing invalid XML, as it doesn't entitize the data. I.e., what happens if either string contains a `<`?

Comment: @ildjarn, the point I'm trying to make is that sometimes you don't need the overhead... Anyways - is there any name on this planet which has a `>`/`<` or `&` in it? How would you even say it? That's just plain daft! Surely any input mechanism will have validated the data by this point anyway.

Comment: Uncommon, sure, but in the USA at least it's certainly *legal* to have special punctuation in one's name.

Comment: @ildjarn, a `>` or `<` ? wow... folks across the pond certainly are *different* ;) Anyways, it's a suggestion to look at a more *lightweight* approach...